# powershell retrieve members of group recursively

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-3.0

I got a pretty big audit project that I'm hoping to automate.

I need to get every user's name, SamAccountName, Title and Department who are part of a group. Problem is, the group has groups within it and those groups have groups within them. Another problem is that about 99% of all the groups have an asterisk in it's Display Name (NOT SamAccountName).

Here is the code I currently have, it works fine until it receives a group with an asterisk in it's name.. (hence the .Replace("*","") part.... Anyone got any ideas on how to fix this?

```
function Get-NestedGroupMember {
[CmdletBinding()] 
param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] 
    [string]$Group 
)
$broke = @();
## Find all members  in the group specified 
$members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group 
foreach ($member in $members){
    ## If any member in  that group is another group just call this function again 
    if ($member.objectClass -eq 'group'){
        $memberGroup = $($member.Name).Replace("*", "")
        try{
            Get-NestedGroupMember -Group "$($memberGroup)"
        }catch{
            $broke += "$($memberGroup)`n"
        }
    }else{
        ## otherwise, just  output the non-group object (probably a user account)
        $member.Name  
    }
}
Write-Host "`nThe following groups could not be found automatically.`n`n$($broke)"
}

$getGroup = Read-Host -Prompt "Group name"

Get-NestedGroupMember $getGroup
```

Comment: And you're not using the `-Recursive` parameter because...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Bill_Stewart said, you are trying to implement functionality that already exists for you. [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) has a -Recursive parameter that will search all of the nested groups and get the members for you. You can then pipe the output to a select and get only the properties you care about.

```
AD:
  TopGroup
    Betty
    Bob
    NestedGroup1
      Joe
      Frank
    NestedGroup2
      George
      Herman
```

Using -Recursive

```
Get-AdGroupMember TopGroup -Recursive | Select-Object SamAccountName
Betty
Bob
Joe
Frank
George
Herman
```